# Возможно ли подключить виджет разработанный для языка PHP на Django

Tags: php, python, django

Я понимаю что вопрос может быть из категории "кране тупого", но у меня никак не уходит надежда после некоторых ответов по поисковым запросам.

Есть [виджет сдек](https://widget.cdek.ru/) серверная часть которого работает на php.
Существует ли способ заставить работать это на Django?

Спрашиваю лишь потому что находил упоминания о библиотеке subprocess которая позволяет исполнить код php внутри pythno и находил какой то случай, где человек в рамках хоста вызывал php файл и заставлял его исполняться, хоть весь его сайт так же на Django.

Сам я конечно пробовал но тк опыта не столь много, то могу просто пробовать не правильно.
Буду благодарен за любую подсказку даже если та будет "не трать на это время" ))

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Ставите php как обычно. В настройках web-сервера указываете, что определенный url на вашем сайте должен запускать php код.

Comment: Если у вас имеется сервер пере Python-ом, т.е., какой-нибудь Nginx или Apach, то вам нужно просто его сконфигурировать таким образом, чтобы определенный URI не отдавался интерпретатору питона, а уже уходил в php через fpm, таким образом, вы можете под одним сервером держать и 10 разных приложений. Что-то подобное уже описано тут: https://serverfault.com/questions/560979/using-single-nginx-server-to-serve-proxy-php-python-and-nodejs